# is it possible to inject value into weblogic.xml from external file?

Tags: java, xml, maven, weblogic, code-injection

i have defined virtual directory directory mapping like below:

```
<virtual-directory-mapping>
    <local-path>${foo}</local-path>
    <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>
</virtual-directory-mapping>
```

The value foo is declared in `pom.xml`. Everything is working properly. But the question is: Can i inject this value from some external file or define this in weblogic directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use maven filtering to replace the values

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>filtered/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
```

or

for weblogic you can use deployment plans - basically you build ear once, and can replace some values based on dev/test/prod environments

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/DEPGD/config.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a single domain, adding environment variables to setDomainEnv or having setDomainEnv source another script seems like a good option